# Remove blank ggplots from a list of ggplots

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, subset

I have a list of ggplots below. Some are blank using `theme_void()`, while others display data. How can I selectively filter out or remove the blank ggplots and make a new list containing only the plots containing data? I am not looking for something like  `ggplot_list[c(-1, -4)]` because I have very long lists of ggplots with many blank plots.

```
library(ggplot2)

 p1 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  theme_void()
 
 p2 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
   geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt))
 
 p3 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
   geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, ))
 
 p4 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
   theme_void()
 
 ggplot_list <- list(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

Comment: You could check what ```theme_void()``` changes (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/theme-defaults.r) and filter based on that. For example use ```lapply(ggplot_list, FUN = function(x) x$theme$rect |> class())```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is not about the theme but about (data) layers.
Given this list:

```
# naming the elements so we can easily follow the result    
ggplot_list <- list(p1 = p1, p2 = p2, p3 = p3, p4 = p4)
```

You could filter `ggplot_list` and keep only those entries for which the `layers` element is not an empty list.

```
tmp <- Filter(\(i) !identical(i$layers, list()), ggplot_list)
```

Result

```
tmp
#
#$p2
#
#$p3
```

---

Examples:

```
p1$layers
# list()

p2$layers
#[[1]]
#mapping: x = ~mpg, y = ~wt 
#geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#position_identity
```